# Regex to restrict only second occurrence of open and close brackets using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string "(BETA) (Feb 27, 2011)"

I need to get the second occurrence of the open and close brackets using C#

Comment: Have you already tried something? If so, could you post it? Or are you simply hoping to be spoon-fed? :)

Comment: Probably not a fair remark.  The guy has answered 187 questions...  But agree that some more information on where he got stuck is better.

Comment: @Stephan, note that I put a smiley after it, so it isn't meant as harsh as it apparently sounds to you (or others). I just think the question isn't asked as it should: for one, there's no question mark anywhere to be seen, the "I need" part sounds a bit demanding to me, and it's unclear what s/he already tried to solve it. And there's the lack of details: I could now simply answer something, like: `s.substring(7)` (pseudo code), which would produce the desired result.

Comment: I was doing it the index of way which i realized may not be ideal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably easiest to match all `(...)` tokens and take the second:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\(([^)]*)\)");
```

Getting the second match:

```
String second = matches[1].Groups[1].Value;
```

The regex assumes valid pairs of parentheses, and no nesting. It is pretty basic:

- `\(` - Opening.
- `(...)` - Capturing group, to easily extract the value.
- `[^)]*` - Content of the group - characters that are not `(`.
- `\)` - Closing.

Comment: You'd need to be careful with inputs such as: (BETA(1))(...) or anything that contains nested parentheses.

Comment: @Stephen - Note the mandatory "The regex assumes valid pairs of parentheses, and no nesting" comment `:)`. There are ways of dealing with that in a .Net regex, but I don't think there's a need to complicate this one, at least until the OP requests it. Matching a balanced token isn't too hard, but it is considerably more complex. Small plug: http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/net-regex-matching-mixed-balanced-parentheses/

Answer (score 2):

Do you want it in regex?  If not regex:

```
int n = text.indexOf("(");
if (n >= 0) {
    n = text.indexOf("(", n+1);
}
```

Regex:

```
\(.+?\)\s*(\(.+?\))
```

Notice the use of a following "?" to force non-aggressive mode.  And you must have at least one character within the parentheses.